# Cannot find out how to format a phone number in tkinter Entry box

Tags: string-formatting, tkinter-entry

I use Python 3.9 with Tkinter.  I would like to create an ttk.Entry widget that would, when a Phone Number is inputted as a string of 10 intigers will automatically insert the () such as (555)234-2299.  Is this possible with what I am using?

Answer (score 0):

> when a Phone Number is inputted as a string of 10 intigers will
> automatically insert the () such as (555)234-2299.

Add namespace `import re`.

Code:

```
import re
print('(%s)%s-%s' % tuple(re.findall(r'\d{4}$|\d{3}', '5552342299')))
```

Result output:

(555)234-2299